# Unity3d; Skybox on mesh like in Source engine.

Tags: unity-game-engine, skybox

In older games Ive made levels in, like unreal or half-life the skybox is a parallaxed texture that you assign to world geometry, for instance, the ceiling of your room, to give the illusion of the room being open to the sky.
There are some neat tricks or weird things you can achieve with this 'sky portal' method. For example you could have 'sky' in an underground room. or walk through a hole in the sky.

I'm wondering is it possible to make a mesh in unity3d render as part of the skybox like in these older engines.

Comment: Anything is possible with the right shader. In the meantime, the [Skybox component](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Skybox.html) will do most of what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this yes. Usually you assign a "SkyBox" to your camera and change the "Clear Flags" for her "SkyBox". However, there are other ways to do.

Learn more here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Skybox.html

Hope this help !